# Laravel passing data toArray() and then checking if in_array throws error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am using Laravel and I fetching the logged in users favourites from a database table. Whilst I am in the view of an article that I am fetching from a CMS API, I am also fetching the logged in users favourites, I want to check if the user has already favourited this article but fetching the favourites and checking if the UID exists within the array and if it does i will output a different styled icon. So I thought I would pass my data as an array and then use the php function `in_array` however I get this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize()
must be of the type array, string given
```

This is how I am retrieving my data:

```
 //fetch article from cms
 $item = $this->client->fetchPage($id);
$favourites = Auth::user()->favourites()->get("article_uid")->toArray();
```

and then in my view

```
  @if (in_array($item->uid, $favourites)) 
      Already a favourite 
@else 
 {{Form::open(['action'=>['FavouritesController@store',$item->UID]])}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="icon-remove-user"></span>Select Favourite</button>
 {{Form::close()}}  
@endif
```

My array is output as so:

```
array(3) {
    [0] = > array(6) {
        ["id"] = > string(1)"1" ["user_id"] = > string(1)"1" ["article_uid"] = > string(14)"testb" ["deleted_at"] = > NULL["created_at"] = > string(20)"-0001-11-30 00:00:00" ["updated_at"] = > string(20)"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    }[1] = > array(6) {
        ["id"] = > string(1)"2" ["user_id"] = > string(1)"1" ["article_uid"] = > string(6)"test" ["deleted_at"] = > NULL["created_at"] = > string(20)"-0001-11-30 00:00:00" ["updated_at"] = > string(20)"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    }[2] = > array(6) {
        ["id"] = > string(1)"3" ["user_id"] = > string(1)"1" ["aritlce_uid"] = > string(18)"testb" ["deleted_at"] = > NULL["created_at"] = > string(19)"2015-02-08 11:25:32" ["updated_at"] = > string(19)"2015-02-08 11:25:32"
    }
}
```

Ideally I want to check the `article_uid` in the `$favourites` array against the `$item->uid`. However I am getting this error, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I think its because my array is more complex than the standard documentation on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Do I need to simplify it before passing it to the view or another method? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the ids as an array, use `lists()`:

```
$favourites = Auth::user()->favourites()->lists("article_uid");
```

---

By the way the error you received is caused by the fact that you passed a string to `get()`. You need to pass an array (even if it's just one column):

```
$favourites = Auth::user()->favourites()->get(["article_uid"])->toArray();
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the error and outputs the array array as so:   `array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "testb" [1]=> string(6) "testb" [2]=> string(18) "testc" }` i've left the `in_array` method untouched but this still outputs the add favourite button event though this is in the array

Comment: Can you echo `$item->uid` to make sure it holds the correct value?